# Product Review post action rewriting not working

Tags: overrides, magento-1.6, controllers

I wrote this code in config.xml, trying to rewrite product review post action.

```
<rewrite>
            <namespace_module>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/review/product/post/#]]></from>
                <to>/module/review/post/</to>
            </namespace_module>
</rewrite>
```

But but when I sumit form this redirecting me to homepage.

I have used this code too Overriding controller.

```
include_once"Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php";
class Namespace_Module_NewController extends Mage_Review_ProductController
{
```

please suggest what I am missing.

Comment: Try including the full path to the file when doing rewrites for controllers.  Example: `require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Review') . DS . 'ProductController.php';`

Comment: Also, the config based rewrites are deprecated in Magento 1.6.  Use Pradeep's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

for overriding the controller.create a custom module.

Step 1: Create a module xml yourpackgename_modulename.xml file at the app/etc/modules with the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourpackagename_Modulename>
            <active>true</active> 
            <codePool>local</codePool> 
        </Yourpackagename_Modulename>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create modules config.xml file at app/code/local/Yourpackgename/Modulename/etc/config.xml with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourpackagename_Modulename>
            <version>0.0.1</version> 
        </Yourpackagename_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <review>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <yourpackagename_modulename before="Mage_Review">Yourpackagename_Modulename</yourpackagename_modulename> 
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </review>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create ProductConroller.php under app/code/local/Yourpackgename/Modulename/controllers/ProductController.php with the following content

```
<?php
    require_once 'Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php';
    class Yourpackagename_Modulename_ProductController extends Mage_Review_ProductController
    {

        public function postAction(){
            // your code comes here
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it has not worked. It is submitting parent postAction() method.

Comment: can you post your actual code here.so that i can check it

Comment: It is exactly same as you have suggested. But on `postAction()`, I just used  `echo "hi"; exit;`

to check it is coming in function or not. But it is not and submitting parent funtion